# Why do application menus open to the left?

Tags: windows-7

I noticed that my menus have started to open to the left for *most* applications. I suspect my son accidentally changes something, but I don't know what.

How can I make them open up to the right?

Opening to the left:

[image: To the left]

Opening to the right:

[image: To the right]

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like the application is opened at the right side of the screen, as it is unable to expand to the right it expands to the left. Could that be possible? What happens when you have Notepad2 maximized and open the File / Edit / View menu?

Comment: Well, that is expected behavior? A full screen screenshot could help remove any confusion.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly I have to agree. This is expected behavior. It opens to the left if and only if there's not room for it to open to the right.  The screenshot is very misleading if there IS in fact room to the right.

Comment: @Synetech - I disagree, it doesn't look like there's any room at all to me.  I don't know what the distinction is, but I see a lot of applications where it insists on trying to be justified with the menu dropdown, so this isn't unusual to me.  Now, if this is happening even when it's maximized, THAT'S unusual.

Comment: I’m not one to nag people about trying Google first, but this was extremely easy to fix. The very [first](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/786-menus-open-left-right-side.html) and [second](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20070225/vista-tip-open-menu-location/) [search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=menus+open+to+the+left) would have solved it (especially for a “software engineer by hobby and trade”).

Comment: @Synetech Although in the first link, the screenshots are mixed up. If you have it set as **right-handed**, the menus are supposed to open to the **right**.

Comment: @iglvzx, hehe yup they got the screenshots/ideas backwards. `:-D` To be honest though, I think this makes more sense in terms of LTR vs. RTL languages than handedness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This setting is related to the **Tablet PC Components**. It looks like your menus have been set to left-handed. You can change it back to right-handed by setting the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
"MenuDropAlignment"="0"
```

Comment: …and tell your son to be more careful. `;-)`

Comment: that fixes it, but my son is 3. I doubt he edited the registry, and I know I didn't :)  I wonder if some tablet setting got switched by default when I plugged in my bamboo writing tablet

Comment: @Joe Most likely, he curiously/haphazardly clicked around in the tablet settings and changed it. But I like the idea of a 3 year old computer genius a little more. :P

Comment: as do I...... :)

Comment: These settings are changeable through control panel, maybe your son got there :) see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to do it from `Control Panel`, `Tablet PC Settings`:

[image]

That way, you don't have to worry about registry.

Comment: If Tablet PC Settings isn't listed in Control Panel, then it can be accessed by pasting this into Run: `explorer shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}`